# ImportError: No module named sslscan

Tags: git, ssl, importerror, network-scan

I am trying to install SSLScan from source. I cloned the git repo from

```
https://github.com/DinoTools/sslscan.git
```

And did the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

I will note however, that the yum repo was installing cmake v2.6, so I hacked it to be 2.8 by doing the following:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install cmake28
cd /usr/bin
mv cmake cmake26
mv ccmake ccmake26
mv cpack cpack26
mv ctest ctest26
ln -s cmake28 cmake
ln -s ccmake28 ccmake
ln -s cpack28 cpack
ln -s ctest28 ctest
```

Don't know what's going on but when I try to run

```
sslscan localhost
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named sslscan
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the module manually by calling:

`./build/python/python setup.py install`

And then run `sslscan` again.